# Predicting values using Bayesian model and getting error

Tags: python, prediction, bayesian, pgmpy

[Dataset file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ignlq1o11jgbkc8/file3.csv?dl=0)I am predicting no_of_people values using bayesian model in python. I am using this dataset given in picture.my error is also attached in the picture [image: Dataset sample]
[image: Error in prediction]

```
#My code is here 
import numpy as np
from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/file3.csv')
train = data[:40]
test = data[40:].drop('no_of_people', axis=1)
restaurant_model = BayesianModel(
[('location', 'cost'),
('quality', 'cost'),
('location', 'no_of_people'),
('cost', 'no_of_people')])
restaurant_model.fit(train)
restaurant_model.get_cpds()
restaurant_model.predict(test).values.ravel()
```

Please help me to solve this problem. How can I predict these values perfectly.

Comment: Pandas 1.1.3
numpy 1.19.2
i don't know about how to check pgmpy version.

Comment: Have you tried it on your pc, your output is okk??

Comment: pgmpy "0.1.13"
I have 60 rows in my dataset, Should I send to you the whole data??

Comment: question edited, please find file3 in Dataset file link

Comment: Have you find it?? @qmeeus

Comment: I don't know how to get help except at stackoverflow. Could you help me to remove this error??

Comment: is there any other good library for Bayesian prediction which could work on continuous data??

Comment: Google is your friend...